# Generate iframe and content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I don't understand why it's not working.

I have a `remote.php` script

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

And a `local.php` script

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() { document_ready(); } );

        function document_ready()
        {
            $('#vcc').click(function() { get_ajax() } );
        }

        function get_ajax()
        {
            $.ajax({ url:"remote.php",context:document.body})
            .done(function(response,context) { get_ajax_done(response,context); } );
        }
        function get_ajax_done(response,context)
        {
            $('<iframe id="myFrame" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"/>').appendTo('#someDiv');
            $('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append(response);
            $('#someDiv').addClass('done');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="someDiv"></div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="vcc" value="Go"></input>
</div>

</body>
```

It's working.  Clicking the button make an ajax call and receive the `Hello World`, the iframe is created ans is visible but contains nothing.

If I put (with firebug) a breakpoint on

```
$('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append(response);
```

then F10, the content appears and remains after F8 !

Comment: Its basically a get call right? Why can't you directly add src="url" in the iframe?

Comment: Because its is a simplified example.  I have something more complex with a post call.  But the main problem remains the same.  The question is not why I do that but why it is not working.

Comment: do u have any css assosiated with your html

Comment: No, full local.php is like above.  And the iframe is displaying.  But contains nothing.  Also controlled content with firebug.  Only contents html,head and body tags.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qh3nLtgg/

Comment: Same result, iframe empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should insert you response when frame loaded:

```
    function get_ajax_done(response,context)
    {
        $('<iframe id="myFrame" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"/>')
        .appendTo('#someDiv')
        .on('load', function(){
           $(this).contents().find('body').append(response);
           $('#someDiv').addClass('done');
        })
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks.  It's working fine.  Like Sandeeproop solution but I prefer yours.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the main problem is that you are not giving browser some time to render iframe into DOM.

Just replace this code

```
$('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append(response);
$('#someDiv').addClass('done');
```

With this

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#myFrame').contents().find('body').append(response);
  $('#someDiv').addClass('done');
},100);
```

Hope this helps

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3becacL/1/)

Comment: YES !  It's working.  Many thanks. But ... I think Andrey solution is 'better' because yours is waiting an arbitrary time and not just the time to load.

Comment: Ya i also felt that that's why i have given him upvote